# Which is more common in Mandarin: 四處 or 周圍?

Tags: mandarin

Which is more common to express the notion of "everywhere": 四處 or 周圍?

Example: The house will have your books everywhere.

Comment: users noting answer would like to also mention 处处 （is even in IME editor)＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂： 处处（副）everywhere；in all aspects.1.表示各个地方（１）十月的田野，处处是盛开的鲜花、飘香的瓜果。（２）中央代表团来到雪城高原，处处受到西藏人民的热烈欢迎。（３）春节前夕，整个中国，处处都洋溢着节日的气象。（４）登上黄山，处处都是美丽的景色，让人流连忘返。（５）外国游客到了中国，处处都感到新鲜。（６）春节庙会上，处处人头攒动，人山人海。２。表示各个方面，6 samples,
comparison w 到处：＂处处＂指各个方面，包括具体和抽象两种处所：＂到处＂表示各个地方，只指具体的处所。(1)九月的北京处处／到处是鲜花。（２）每到春节，中国处处／到处是欢快、喜庆的场面。（３）老师处处／＊到处关心我们。（４）妈妈到中国来一次很不容易，我想陪她到处／＊处处看看。（５）他处处／＊到处严格要求自己。（６）我到处／＊处处找他也没找到。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

四處 is better than 周圍 in this case. However, I think you can consider 到處.

The house will have your books everywhere.
這房子將到處都有你的書。

From Google Translate:

> everywhere 副詞
>       到處
>       everywhere, throughout, in all places
>       隨處
>       everywhere, anywhere
>       遍
>       all over, everywhere
>       隨地
>       anywhere, everywhere
>       普
>       everywhere
>       廣泛地
>       abroad, diffusely, everywhere, large, at large, proverbially
>       在在
>       everywhere

Comment: My friend also said 到處 is more common. Thanks!

Comment: Are there cases where 周圍 is better than 四處?

Comment: 周圍 means surrounding; ( around and nearby ).
四處 means everywhere.
I think they are different.
Some examples for 周圍:
大樓周圍有不少警察。
學校周圍要保持安靜。
We cannot use 四處 in these cases, but 四周 is ok.

Answer (score 3):

The '四' in '四處' is a 虛數 (symbolic number) that represents 'All'

'**四處**' literally means 'all places/ every places' which means the same as '**everywhere**' It can also describe '**all over the place**'

'周圍' means 'around' , typically refer to the area around an object

For example: '周圍都是樹' (tree are all around) *the object is omitted here*

'四周圍' means 'all around'

Consider the following:

- '房子裡**四處**都有你的書'(there are books **everywhere** in your house)
- '房子裡**四周圍**都有你的書'(there are books **all around** in your house)
- '房子**四周圍**都有樹 (there are trees **all around** the house)

> Which is more common to express the notion of "everywhere"

The answer is 四處

> young99 wrote: *I think you can consider 到處*

'到處' literally means 'Everywhere (you go)'